# Fontawesome is not working in mdbootstrap and rails

Tags: mdbootstrap

I am Using
Rails → 5.2
ruby → 2.4
MDBootstrap

I am using 3 separate  bootstrap related frameworks they are 
     sb-admin-2(old version),
     cardoor template,
     mdbootstrap

sb-admin 2 is used in app/assets
 cardoor is used in vendor/cardoor/

I am using custom layout setup root contains

```
-vendor
 -customer
  -font
  -img
  -javascripts
  -stylesheets
```

stylesheets folder contains following files

```
vendor/customer/stylesheets/all.css
vendor/customer/stylesheets/bootstrap.css
vendor/customer/stylesheets/font-awesome.css
vendor/customer/stylesheets/mdb.css
vendor/customer/stylesheets/mdb.lite.css
vendor/customer/stylesheets/mdb.lite.min.css
vendor/customer/stylesheets/mdb.min
vendor/customer/stylesheets/customer.css
```

instead of application.css I have used customer.css

**vendor/customer/stylesheets/customer.css**

```
   /*

   *= require customer/stylesheets/bootstrap
   *= require customer/stylesheets/bootstrap.min
   *= require customer/stylesheets/mdb
   *= require customer/stylesheets/mdb.lite
   *= require customer/stylesheets/mdb.lite.min
   *= require customer/stylesheets/mdb
   *= require customer/stylesheets/all
   *= require customer/stylesheets/font-awesome
   *= require customer/stylesheets/style
   *= require customer/stylesheets/style.min
   *= require customer/stylesheets/addons/datatables-select
   *= require customer/stylesheets/addons/datatables-select.min
   *= require customer/stylesheets/addons/datatables
   *= require customer/stylesheets/addons/datatables.min
   *= require customer/stylesheets/addons/directives
    *= require customer/stylesheets/addons/directives.min
   *= require customer/stylesheets/addons/flag
   *= require customer/stylesheets/addons/flag.min
   *= require customer/stylesheets/addons/rating
   *= require customer/stylesheets/addons/rating.min
   *= require selectize
   *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
   *= require selectize.default
   *= require select2.min
```

**initializers/assets.rb**

```
     Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( rtt_demo/stylesheets/rtt_demo.css )
    Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( rtt_demo/javascripts/rtt_demo.js )
```

**layouts/customer.html.erb**

```
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'rtt_demo/stylesheets/rtt_demo', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag 'rtt_demo/javascripts/rtt_demo', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

**I am getting the following error** and fontawesome icon is not displaying

downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" style:normal weight:900 stretch:100 src index:2): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:3000/assets/customer/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff

downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" style:normal weight:900 stretch:100 src index:3): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:3000/assets/customer/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf

downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" style:normal weight:900 stretch:100 src index:1): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:3000/assets/customer/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2

Comment: Are you including the font awesome css/js in your application layout?

Comment: In my application.html.erb file I have already accessing separate template i have updated my question